# Is there a simple way to loop over stdin in Guava?

Tags: java, guava

In Apache Commons, I can write:

```
LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(System.in, "utf-8");
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String line = it.nextLine();
    // do something with line
}
```

Is there anything similar in Guava?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, to start with...this isn't something you particularly need a library for, given that it's doable with just the straight JDK as

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,
  Charsets.UTF_8));
// okay, I guess Charsets.UTF_8 is Guava, but that lets us not worry about
// catching UnsupportedEncodingException
while (reader.ready()) {
  String line = reader.readLine();
}
```

but if you want it to be more collections-y Guava provides [`List<String> CharStreams.readLines(Readable)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#readLines-java.lang.Readable-).

I think we don't provide an `Iterator` because there isn't really any good way to deal with the presence of `IOException`s.  Apache's `LineIterator` appears to silently catch an `IOException` and close the iterator out, but...that seems like a confusing, risky, and not always correct approach.  Basically, I think the "Guava approach" here is either to either read the whole input into a `List<String>` all at once, or to do the `BufferedReader`-style loop yourself and decide how *you* want to deal with the potential presence of `IOException`s.

Most of Guava's I/O utilities, in general, are focused on streams that can be closed and reopened, like files and resources, but not really like `System.in`.

Comment: If you really want to do it without Guava, then you could use [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) from Java 7. But hard-coding UTF-8 is probably not the best idea anyway (unless you primarily accept well-specified input as opposed to user interaction on stdin).

Comment: Oh, so they _did_ add that in Java 7.  Took them long enough.

Comment: Yes, someone took a few hints ;-)

Comment: Thanks. `reader.nextLine` should be `reader.readLine`, though.

Answer (score 9):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");
while(sc.hasNext()) {
  String next = sc.nextLine();
}
```

You don't need guava for this

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 `BufferedReader` has new method [`lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) which returns a stream of lines, which you can easily consume:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
reader.lines()
    .forEach(line -> { // or any other stream operation
      // process liness
    })
```